# OleDb return Date Column value with time

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have Excel File(.xls) which contain date column without time value.  I am trying to read this file and put it in datatable with connection string as below:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Test\Desktop\1.xls; Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text"
```

**Excel File Data**

[image]

OleDb return datem value with time. 7/20/1995 12:00:00 AM

**DataTable Data**

[image]

But i want datem column value without time. Anyone have idea what i have to do to solve my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Just put a format on the column.

Answer (score 1):

.Net framework's `DateTime` consist of Date and Time. You can't really separate `Time` part from `DateTime`, instead you can use custom format for displaying records.

```
string str = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: Here is a list of datetime format 
http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I know that I can get only date via custom format. But actually I want

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's just a display issue in the `DataSet` visualizer. Actually it's a `DateTime` column which has no inherent format. So if you want to output a DateTime only with the date part:

```
string date = dt.ToShortDateString(); // or dt.ToString("d")
```

[**The Short Date ("d") Format Specifier**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#ShortDate)